# Dangling? I need some help

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, coordination

> "Some seagulls squawked briefly when she stepped by them and **quickly flapped away.**"

I wonder that the bold part modifies for "some seagulls" or "when she stepped by them"?

p/s: I added a comma to make sure the bold part modifies for "some seagulls".Is it correct?

> "Some seagulls squawked briefly when she stepped by **them,** and **quickly flapped away.**"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*And quickly flapped away* isn't a modifier, so it doesn't modify anything.  It's one of two coordinated predicates:

```
Some seagulls
    [squawked briefly when she stepped by them] 
    [and quickly flapped away]
.
```

Both bracketed phrases predicate on the subject *some seagulls*.  Neither is a modifier.